# Plotting legend by a column variable - legend does not match plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to create a plot where the legend is based on the point description, ie. the plot is labelled by (in this case) colour.

Here is my dataframe, x:

```
xnum=c(1,2,3,4)
xdesc=c("yellow","red","blue","yellow")
xnum2=c(1,2,3,4)
x=data.frame(xnum,xnum2,xdesc)
```

Here is the code that I used to plot it:

```
plot(x[,1],x[,2],pch=as.numeric(x[,3]))
legend("topleft",legend=levels(as.factor(unique(x[,3]))),pch=as.numeric(x[,3]),cex=0.8,horiz=T)
```

[image: plot]
However, from the image you can see that the legend does not match the plot (the first and the last points should be labelled as yellow and not blue). I thought this was the correct method for matching the legend to the plot based on a column variable - where am I going wrong?

Comment: What should the legend look like?

Comment: remove the as.numeric(). R will recognise those colour names.

Comment: The first and the last points (the ones with the +) should be labelled as yellow, not blue

Comment: The colour names were just examples, I need it to work with different variables

Comment: Did you ever look at the output of `levels(as.factor(unique(x[,3])))`    ? 
`[1] "blue"   "red"    "yellow"`

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how to correct it

Comment: try `rev(levels(as.factor(unique(x[,3]))))`